# How to make a button to overlay all objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, button, overlay, flash

I'm currently making a flash application. In the application, I'm loading an swf file inside a frame. Here's the code:

```
stop();

var url1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Complete The Words Game 1.swf");
myLoader.load(url1);
addChild(myLoader);
myLoader.scaleX = 1.8;
myLoader.scaleY = 1.8;
myLoader.x = 190;

addChild(backtopractice_button);
backtopractice_button.x=20;
backtopractice_button.y=610;
backtopractice_button.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, backtopractice);
```

And I want to bring the "backtopractice_button" to the very front to overlay everything, even the SWF file too. Is it possible to do this? and how do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: By using [`addChild()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29), you already put the button on top of the loader: `The child is added to the front (top) of all other children in this DisplayObjectContainer instance.` If the button is not appearing on top, you have some other code that does this. You should post this other code.

Comment: try not to have spaces in the external file name that you load.